# Where do I find data of all companies in this world?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

In sites like facebook, a user can add his work position by typing few words and selecting the company

How do they get that data and how can I get that data so our users can also add work position the same way ?

Comment: this is a pretty broad question, but it also sounds like you want technical solutions...can you clarify exactly what you want? an open data set of glocal companies? the functionality of linkedin?

Comment: No, I dont need tech help, I mentioned about dropdown/typing etc to explain  the requirement. I actually want to know how to get/download that data. Please let me know for any questions.

Comment: Crunchbase has a lot of good data. You could scrape it. I would consider that as a supplement to the much higher quality but less rich government data sources.

Answer (score 4):

Open Corporates is the largest public database of corporations in the world; they have a slew of data/apis/etc.
[Open Corporates](https://opencorporates.com/)

EDIT:
I'm not 100% on how to use Open Corporates, but after a quick peek, it looks pretty easy/straight forward; [I did a search for "bulk"](https://opencorporates.com/companies?jurisdiction_code=&q=bulk)  and it returns results that you can peek at individually and/or download as Open Data (XML/JSON) or as an Enterprise User (CSV/XLS).
NOTE: I have no clue what the difference between the two user types are, and the differentiation between data formats for each, in this context. Very interested about this, I am.

Comment: How to download data from that ?

Comment: see the edited comment

Answer (score 2):

1) A lot of data is kept secret and is not open. It will be from official sources and also user contributed
2) Many networks offer API access though so (within limits) you don't need the entire dataset, you just need to know how to construct an AJAX request in your form where people add work position

For *Facebook* the **ATLAS API** has a [company object within the Organization endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/atlas-api/reference/objects/company/v2.6):

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mat's answer, proprietary information is available, but here are a few open source approaches:

1. Wikipedia: [A list of notable companies in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_of_the_United_States)
2. Forbes: [List of Largest Private Companies](http://www.forbes.com/largest-private-companies/list/#tab:rank)
3. Forbes: [The World's Biggest Public Companies](http://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall)

Anything past this, go down to your local library and access the list of companies via [InfoGroup's ReferenceUSA](http://resource.referenceusa.com/). The huge flag on this data approach is the proprietary nature of the database.

Answer (score 1):

We run a website called https://www.tofler.in that provides data for all companies in India. We have an API as well with a certain number of free requests daily as well. Documentation can be found at https://www.tofler.in/docs

Comment: is this service free and open?

Comment: @albert Yes. Just that there is a daily limit on the number of requests that you can place to the service. Depending on your use-case limits can be raised significantly as well.